# PHP to write a JS script into my html source doc

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to use PHP to write a JS script into my html source doc. I have investigated numerous other forums, but still can't quite identify the error..

The JS script I am trying to embed follows syntax from a default YUI Charting Library script.

Assuming my php string output (generated from the ***echo: $data->dump_yui($row_numbers=false, $col_letters=false, $sheet=0, $table_class='excel');*** ) appropriately suits the parameters r'qd by the YUI script syntax, where am I going wrong with embedding the script in my html doc?

PHP written to JavaScript in the HTML :

```
<?php 
echo "<script language=javascript>";
echo 'document.write("YUI().use('charts',function(Y){var myDataValues = [';
echo $data->dump_yui($row_numbers=false, $col_letters=false, $sheet=0, $table_class='excel');
echo "<br>];<br><br>var styleDef = {series:<br>{Stock:{line:{color:'#898DD5'},marker:{fill:{color:'#eee',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#222',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},over:{fill:{color:'#eee'},border:{color:'#000'},width:9,height:9}}},<br>Liability:{line:{color:'#171944'},marker:{fill:{color:'#eee',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#222',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},over:{fill:{color:'#eee'},border:{color:'#000'},width:9,height:9}}},<br>Shipment:{line:{color:'#ff0000',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},marker:{fill:{color:'#eee',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#ff0000',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},over:{fill:{color:'#ff0000',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#000',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},width:16,height:16}}},<br>Production:{line:{color:'#FFD700',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},marker:{fill:{color:'#eee',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#FFD700',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},over:{fill:{color:'#FFD700',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#000',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},width:16,height:16}}},<br>Order:{line:{color:'#006400',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},marker:{fill:{color:'#eee',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#006400',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},over:{fill:{color:'#006400',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#000',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},width:16,height:16}}}}};<br>var myAxes={dateRange:{keys:['date'],position:'bottom',type:'category',title:'Date Range',styles:{majorTicks:{display:'none'},label:{rotation:-45,margin:{top:5}},title:{fontSize:'90%'}}}};var mychart=new Y.Chart({dataProvider:myDataValues,interactionType:'planar',render:'#mychart',categoryKey:'Date',styles:styleDef,categoryType:'time',horizontalGridlines:{styles:{line:{color:'#fff'}}},verticalGridlines:{styles:{line:{color:'#fff'}}}});<br>});";
echo '");';
echo "</script>";
?>
```

(I have also tried executing the script without the 'document.write' included)

I am fairly green to PHP.. Any ideas?

***_*__
Update (Jul 18, 12):
Thanks for feedback - I tried all of the fixes, and chart is still not rendering, with code:**

```
<?php 
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo 'document.write("YUI().use(\'charts\',function(Y){var myDataValues = [';
echo $data->dump_yui($row_numbers=false, $col_letters=false, $sheet=0, $table_class='excel');
echo "\n];\n\nvar styleDef = {series:\n{Stock:{line:{color:'#898DD5'},marker:{fill:{color:'#eee',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#222',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},over:{fill:{color:'#eee'},border:{color:'#000'},width:9,height:9}}},<br>Liability:{line:{color:'#171944'},marker:{fill:{color:'#eee',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#222',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},over:{fill:{color:'#eee'},border:{color:'#000'},width:9,height:9}}},<br>Shipment:{line:{color:'#ff0000',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},marker:{fill:{color:'#eee',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#ff0000',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},over:{fill:{color:'#ff0000',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#000',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},width:16,height:16}}},<br>Production:{line:{color:'#FFD700',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},marker:{fill:{color:'#eee',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#FFD700',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},over:{fill:{color:'#FFD700',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#000',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},width:16,height:16}}},<br>Order:{line:{color:'#006400',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},marker:{fill:{color:'#eee',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#006400',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},over:{fill:{color:'#006400',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#000',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},width:16,height:16}}}}};<br>var myAxes={dateRange:{keys:['date'],position:'bottom',type:'category',title:'Date Range',styles:{majorTicks:{display:'none'},label:{rotation:-45,margin:{top:5}},title:{fontSize:'90%'}}}};var mychart=new Y.Chart({dataProvider:myDataValues,interactionType:'planar',render:'#mychart',categoryKey:'Date',styles:styleDef,categoryType:'time',horizontalGridlines:{styles:{line:{color:'#fff'}}},verticalGridlines:{styles:{line:{color:'#fff'}}}});<br>});";
echo '");';
echo "</script>";
?>
```

****_**
Update (Jul 20, 12):

Thanks for the additional feedback everyone. I pushed a page up to my server that contains the three code snippets (in a somewhat organized fashion).

---

- http://demo.opendataregistry.com/dashboard/Jacobs_PHP_thanks_for_taking_a_look.html

---

... still can't manage to squash this bug!

Comment: You should also change <script language=javascript> to <script> or <script type='text/javascript'>

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
echo 'document.write("YUI().use('charts',function(Y){var myDataValues = [';
```

The is a problem with the "charts" apostrophe. It shoud be, for exemple:

```
echo 'document.write("YUI().use("charts",function(Y){var myDataValues = [';
```

Comment: I made those changes, no luck, but it must be something minor.. see my updated code above. My text editor is giving me an error (while code it in PHP doc) on the line starting with 'document.write..

Comment: The problem must be in this line: "echo $data->dump_yui($row_numbers=false, $col_letters=false, $sheet=0, $table_class='excel');". If you comment it you can see the rest of the code working... so... are you colling the right object? i suggest a "var_dump($data);die;" before this echo, and you'll be able to see if is empty or not

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what the other guys have mentioned, you also have a whole bunch of `<br>` elements within your JavaScript code, which is not valid. You will have to get rid of those.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to escape you single quote:

`echo 'document.write("YUI().use(\'charts\',function(Y){var myDataValues = [';`

And replace `<br />` by `\n`.

```
echo "\n];\n\nvar styleDef = {series:\n{Stock:{line:{color:'#898DD5'},marker:{fill:{color:'#eee',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#222',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},over:{fill:{color:'#eee'},border:{color:'#000'},width:9,height:9}}},<br>Liability:{line:{color:'#171944'},marker:{fill:{color:'#eee',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#222',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},over:{fill:{color:'#eee'},border:{color:'#000'},width:9,height:9}}},<br>Shipment:{line:{color:'#ff0000',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},marker:{fill:{color:'#eee',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#ff0000',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},over:{fill:{color:'#ff0000',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#000',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},width:16,height:16}}},<br>Production:{line:{color:'#FFD700',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},marker:{fill:{color:'#eee',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#FFD700',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},over:{fill:{color:'#FFD700',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#000',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},width:16,height:16}}},<br>Order:{line:{color:'#006400',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},marker:{fill:{color:'#eee',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#006400',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},over:{fill:{color:'#006400',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},border:{color:'#000',alpha:0,wmode:'transparent'},width:16,height:16}}}}};<br>var myAxes={dateRange:{keys:['date'],position:'bottom',type:'category',title:'Date Range',styles:{majorTicks:{display:'none'},label:{rotation:-45,margin:{top:5}},title:{fontSize:'90%'}}}};var mychart=new Y.Chart({dataProvider:myDataValues,interactionType:'planar',render:'#mychart',categoryKey:'Date',styles:styleDef,categoryType:'time',horizontalGridlines:{styles:{line:{color:'#fff'}}},verticalGridlines:{styles:{line:{color:'#fff'}}}});<br>});";
```

Comment: I made those changes, no luck, but it must be something minor.. see my updated code above. My text editor is giving me an error (while code it in PHP doc) on the line starting with 'document.write..

Comment: I don't see any error. You can check it here: http://www.piliapp.com/php-syntax-check/ Your code doesn t have any error. Can you execute it ?

Comment: Thanks for the additional feedback charles. I pushed a page up to my server that contains the three code snippets (in a somewhat organized fashion). If you have a second to take a glance over, I'd have much gratitude. Code is for an open source registry project for sustainable commerce analytics - so your help is helping a pretty good cause! (url: http://demo.opendataregistry.com/dashboard/Jacobs_PHP_thanks_for_taking_a_look.html)

Comment: In this page http://demo.opendataregistry.com/dashboard/dashboard2.html there is still <br> in Javascript (look the source code and search for "myDataValues")